# Excel VBA SQL query does not return any results

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm trying to run a SQL query with Excel VBA (see below).  MySale is a string variable and is based on a dropdown list and is either Yes or No.

The problem is that no results are returned.  I've checked and Yes appears in the [Sold] column.  Both BOF and EOF are true.

When I check the MySale variable it appears as "Yes".

The values in the {Sold} field are either Yes or No.  The data in the [Sold} field is formatted as General.  This field also has the Wrap Text property set to True.  There are no spaces either before or after Yes or No.

I'm thinking it has to be a data issue because I tested it with other string variables and the correct results are returned.

The last thing I was going to try was to replace the value in the [Sold] column with a text "Yes" or text "No".  However that seems like an extra step that is not necessary.

I'm wondering if Yes / No is being evaluated as True / False.  I tried using True / False and that did not work either.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for your help in adavance.........

```
vsql = "SELECT [Field1], [Field2], [Field3], [Field4], [Field5], [Field6] " & _
       "FROM [Data$] WHERE [Sold] = '" & MySale & "'"
```

Comment: Please share your code of creating ADODB.Connection and connection string.

Comment: @taller...........Thanks......it looks like the first 50 cells in that column are blank.  Once I fill in the blank cells, the sql statement above works as intended.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I had trouble with the query showing values where the result would be blank in Excel. Upon research found the "text" field was actually defined as nvarchar(max).  In order to have it show in excel had to convert the field to text.